# Windows Time Zone Identifiers not supported in .NET 6 Blazor WASM

Tags: timezone, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

According to
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis,
with .NET 6 we should be able to use both IANA and Windows Time Zone identifier formats.

However this doesn't work in Blazor WASM (client side), where only IANA format seems to be recognized.

Does anyone know if this is the intended behaviour or a bug or a WIP?

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I don't believe that the Windows to IANA mappings from ICU/CLDR are currently included in Blazor WASM, which are necessary for the conversion to work properly.  You should raise an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime.  Also, if you really need to do this in Blazor, you can use [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/timezoneconverter).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint issue raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design as this issue ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40440)) tells. When passing data between Blazor and JavaScript, every data get serialized and passed and then de-serialized to use in other runtime (Marshalling). .Net `DateTimeOffset` only can be get from IANA format in JSON Deserialization (`"2020-05-21T02:33:11.188+01:30"`):